# Unable to load the Audience Manager Service client

Tags: web8.5, outbound-email

We are using SDL web 8.5 and DXA 2.0 Java. After saving contact we are getting below 500 error in java web application.

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load the Audience Manager Service client

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load the Audience Manager Service client
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:565)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:291)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load the Audience Manager Service client
    com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact.<init>(Contact.java:712)
    com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact.<init>(Contact.java:680)
    org.apache.jsp.test_002dcontact_jsp._jspService(test_002dcontact_jsp.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:291)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause

com.sdl.audiencemanager.odata_client.AudienceManagerClientException: Unable to load the Audience Manager Service client
    com.sdl.audiencemanager.odata_client.AudienceManagerServiceClient.<init>(AudienceManagerServiceClient.java:65)
    com.sdl.audiencemanager.odata_client.AudienceManagerServiceClient.getInstance(AudienceManagerServiceClient.java:81)
    com.sdl.audiencemanager.profile.Contact.fromIdentificationKeys(Contact.java:74)
    com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact.<init>(Contact.java:697)
    com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact.<init>(Contact.java:680)
    org.apache.jsp.test_002dcontact_jsp._jspService(test_002dcontact_jsp.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:291)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause

com.sdl.audiencemanager.exceptions.AudienceManagerException: Unable to find a Publication mapping for the current Publication: 10. Try adding a 

synchronization target to this Publication.
    com.sdl.audiencemanager.odata_client.AudienceManagerCapabilities.getSyncTargetIdFromPublicationMappings

(AudienceManagerCapabilities.java:48)
    com.sdl.audiencemanager.odata_client.AudienceManagerCapabilities.loadAudienceManagerCapabilities

(AudienceManagerCapabilities.java:33)
    com.sdl.audiencemanager.odata_client.AudienceManagerCapabilities.<init>(AudienceManagerCapabilities.java:29)
    com.sdl.audiencemanager.odata_client.AudienceManagerServiceClient.<init>(AudienceManagerServiceClient.java:52)
    com.sdl.audiencemanager.odata_client.AudienceManagerServiceClient.getInstance(AudienceManagerServiceClient.java:81)
    com.sdl.audiencemanager.profile.Contact.fromIdentificationKeys(Contact.java:74)
    com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact.<init>(Contact.java:697)
    com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.Contact.<init>(Contact.java:680)
    org.apache.jsp.test_002dcontact_jsp._jspService(test_002dcontact_jsp.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:291)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: The stack trace says the following: "Unable to find a Publication mapping for the current Publication: 10. Try adding a synchronization target to this Publication." Can you verify whether this is the culprit?

Comment: @AtilaSos The synchronization target is already added but still we are getting this error

Comment: You also have to ensure that your AM Sync Service is registered as Capability and associated with your AM Sync Target. See https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-4C4ED3B3-92E1-43F7-8D3C-873B572128CD